# New Facebook API (Live feed no longer refreshing)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

From what I understand, Facebook has updated their APIs and my code is now outdated. I have looked on here for an answer and there are some good ones, I just cant seem to put it all together. Here is what I have:

```
 string url = "http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=" + feedID + "&format=json";

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

            bindPosts(json);
```

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's deprecated sind January 28th, 2015.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_2

> The Pages JSON feed (e.g. `https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=%2019292868552&format=json`) is now deprecated and will stop returning data from Jan 28, 2015 onwards. **Developers should instead call the feed edge on the Graph API's Page object: `/v2.4/{page_id}/feed`.**

Comment: okay so i have the url https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/320479643298/feed?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAM.........           but It still is not refreshing

Comment: What do you mean by "refreshing"? Does the call succeed or not?